# How can you deploy from bitbucket if your host doesn't allow git?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm collaborating with someone on a repo managed with bitbucket, and want to be able to deploy to a development server which unfortunately doesn't allow git (lightningbase).

I want to at least be able to push the repo up to the server one way and came across deploybutton.com as a means of doing so -- but it doesn't work and they don't offer support.

It connects (via SSH) to the server okay, then gets permission to connect to bitbucket, but when it comes to actually deploy it fails. I get a flash of a message which says something about bitbucket keys which disappears before I have chance to read it.

Anyone have any experience with deploybutton, or know another way for me to push from bitbucket without git on the server?

As you may have guessed, I'm new to this version control thing...

Comment: I managed to get deploybutton working. The issue was simple: I was collaborating with someone and they created the repo and shared it with me, which is not the same as me being an administrator. Solution: in bitbucket make a team project with both of us as admins. Only had partial success, though, because although it says successfully deployed, the log says "bash: line 1: sshfs: command not found", and nothing actually changed on the server. Still, that's progress of some kind...

Comment: i recommend using `TortoiseGit` (freeware) is better explorer with bitbucket or github, look a tutorial http://guganeshan.com/blog/setting-up-git-and-tortoisegit-with-bitbucket-step-by-step.html or searh google more tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I am not sure which one your are asking, but I will try to address both.
First, if you want to deploy GIT to a server with out GIT create a git commit hook and use command line to copy the files you want to deploy.  You can find tons of information on git hooks in the git book http://git-scm.com/book.  As far as transferring files over ssh, that is most likely handled better a post of its own.

Second, I took a quick look at deploybutton and I think that it wants your sshkey so that it can deploy without a pass word to the remote server.  You will have to generate an sshkey put it on your server and upload it to deploybutton.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas. I will take a look at the git hook docs to see if that is what I need.

With deploybutton there's no documentation (that I can find) and it doesn't ask me for an SSH key at any point, so I'm at a loss there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what all is involved with your deployment process - sometimes that can be a complex affair.

But if you just want to copy files, what's wrong with good old SFTP ?

It would go something like this:

- Get latest from bitbucket on your local machine
- SFTP to lightningbase
- Copy the files

Some SFTP programs (eg: [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_synchronize_full)) have options to 'synchronize' directories - delete files that don't exist locally, and add ones that do. A simple copy would not handle this.

I'm not familiar with ligtningbase or deploybutton in particular, but the above is a pretty common procedure for simple stuff.

Comment: Thanks jwd, but I was hoping to make it easier and to only have to update changes (via FTP or otherwise) rather than having to upload everything every time.

Comment: @terraling If lightningbase supports rsync, that would do it very efficiently. WinSCP's synchronize function (linked in answer) also will give you a list of only what is changed. Would be nice to just `git push`, of course (:

Comment: I'm Mac, but I've found cyberduck will do FTP syncing so will give that a whirl, thanks...

Answer (score 1):

You can try http://ftploy.com for easy deployment from git/bitbucket to your server

Comment: Hi, ftploy is FTP-only, not SFTP, and so wouldn't work with my host. I've since managed to get a response from deploybutton who had a server issue that has now been fixed, and everything is working okay. For the sake of completeness, I in the meantime came across deployhq.com, and was also able to deploy with them.

Comment: SFTP should be added to ftploy soon according to their blog, just FYI

Comment: Hi, I'm the founder of FTPloy. I just wanted to let you know that we've now released SSH deployments.

Comment: FTPloy are really taking the mickey with their pricing though.  £6 per month for ftping a max of 10 repos...

Answer (score -1):

[DeployHQ](https://www.deployhq.com) is a fantastic tool for deploying from Bitbucket to servers that don't support Git.